# Consulta sobre atrapar excepciones dentro de una funcion - C#

Tags: c#

Me estaba preguntando si podia atrapar todas las excepciones dentro de una funcion, para eso me plantee el siguiente ejemplo.

Mi duda es principalmente si puedo atrapar dividebyzeroexception dentro de la definicion de la funcion y no desde fuera.

```
 static int division(int a, int b)
    {
        try
        {
            if (a == 5)
            {
                throw new miexcep();
            }
            return a / b;

        }
        catch (miexcep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A no puede ser 5!!");
        }



        return a / b;
    }



try
        {
            division(5, 0);

        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B no puede ser 0");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Como dice la documentación oficial de Microsoft acerca de **try/catch** (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)

> Es posible utilizar más de una cláusula catch específica en la misma 
>   instrucción try-catch. En este caso, el orden de las cláusulas catch es 
>   importante, puesto que las cláusulas catch se examinan por orden. Detectar 
>   las excepciones más específicas antes que las menos específicas. El 
>   compilador genera un error si ordena los bloques de detección para que un 
>   bloque posterior nunca pueda alcanzarse.

Debes ordenar los bloques de catch de mas específica a menos, ya que si entra dentro de un bloque de catch, ignorará los siguientes.
Un ejemplo:

```
static int division(int a, int b)
{
    try
    {
        if (a == 5)
        {

        }
        return a / b;

    }
    catch (DividedByZeroException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excepción mas específica.");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Excepción más genérica.");
    }
} 


division(5, 0);
```

Nota: Tambien podrias añadir un **finally**, que es un bloque que se ejecuta independientemente de si se puede ejecutar lo de dentro del try o no (aunque puede que para tu caso no sea tan útil).

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te refieres a lo siguiente:

```
static int division(int a, int b)
    {
        try
        {
            if (a == 5)
            {
                throw new miexcep();
            }
            return a / b;

        }
        catch (miexcep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A no puede ser 5!!");
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B no puede ser 0");
        }


        return a / b;
    } 



division(5, 0);
```

Comment: Claro eso habia hecho al principio, pero si te fijas cuando termina el proceso, alfinal pasa del ultimo catch al segundo return a/b y ahi no esta atrapada, entonces, si te muestra controlada la primera parte ,pero el segundo return es obligatorio entonces, al ejecutar te muestra el segundo return no esta controlado. Finalmente conclui que para que quede atrapado sin problemas tenia que atraparlo desde fuera, pero queria saber si se podia desde dentro.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que enfocas mal el asunto. En tu caso quieres lanzar la excepcion propia cuando a = 5. Entonces deberias pensar tu codigo de esta manera:

```
static int division(int a, int b)
{
    if(a==5)
        throw new miexcep();

     try {
         return a / b;
     } catch (divideByZeroException e) {
         throw e;
     }
}
```

Es decir, si a==5, lanzas directamente tu excepcion personalizada. En caso de que sea distinto, el codigo continua e intenta un try-catch para devolver la division. Capturas la excepcion (en este caso la divideByZero) y la devuelves directamente.

y para llamar a la funcion division:

```
try {
    division(5,0);
} catch (miexcep e) {
    Console.WriteLine("A no puede ser 5");
} catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("B no puede ser 0");
}
```